# Using the process object with multiple arguments

Tags: vb.net, process, process.start

I have a piece of code that calls `MSTEST` with multiple arguments defining a specific set of tests to run and an environment to run it in. Currently the code looks like this (a bit messy but it works):

```
Process.Start(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("VS110COMNTOOLS") 
    & "..\Ide\MSTEST.EXE", "/Testsettings:""" & rwSettings & """" 
    & " /Testcontainer:""" & rwContainer & """" & " /Resultsfile:""" 
    & rwResults & """")
```

With the various variables defined previously. I had to use the `GetEnvironmentVariable("VS110COMNTOOLS")` call because I can't guarantee an install location for Visual Studio and need access to the `MSTEST` executable. `"..\Ide\MSTEST.EXE"` is because the environment variable will only get me to the right area and I'll need to have the system navigate to `IDE` before it finds `MSTEST`.

I want to clean this up because it's not very elegant or readable, and also because I want to be able to raise events running this process. However, I'm not seeing [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on how the `Process` class handles arguments. How can I have the `Process` object I create handle the multiple arguments (that might have spaces in the name)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this:

```
Dim Testsettings As String = "/Testsettings:"""
Dim Testcontainer As String = " /Testcontainer:"""
Dim Resultsfile As String = " /Resultsfile:"""
Dim Quote As String = """"

Dim p As New Process()
p.StartInfo.FileName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("VS110COMNTOOLS") 
                       & "..\Ide\MSTEST.EXE"
p.StartInfo.Arguments = Testsettings & rwSettings & Quote & Testcontainer 
                        & rwContainer & Quote & Resultsfile & rwResults & Quote

p.Start()
```